# How can I run two dependent threads but still controlling when they should exactly be executed?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a dummy opcua server that generates values randomly.
I created a client that has to read the values from the server and every 10 seconds, it should store these values in log files.
As the server is very fast, storing data right after reading the values for 10 seconds may lead to delaying the client to read the new generated data by the server. That's why I thought about using multithreading.

I've set two threads: one thread for reading the client, and the second one for storing the data.

The way the threads should work is the following;
first the code needs to read from the client, once the cycle of 10 seconds is done, the thread of storing the data is triggered but it should not interrupt the other thread from reading.

```
from opcua import Client
import time
from datetime import datetime
import threading


class client:
    def __init__(self, url="opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:8080", store_cycle = 10, read_cycle=1):
        self.url = url
        self.store_cycle = store_cycle
        self.read_cycle = read_cycle
    def connect_to_server(self):
        clt = Client(self.url)
        clt.connect()
        var1 = clt.get_node("ns=2;s=var1_val")
        var2 = clt.get_node("ns=2;s=var2_val")
        return var1,var2


    def read_from_client(self,var1,var2):
        iterator = 0
        logs = []
        dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss")
        while iterator < (self.store_cycle/self.read_cycle):
            iterator+=1

            val1 = var1.get_value()
            val2 = var2.get_value()

            time.sleep(self.read_cycle)

            logs.append(f"datachange_notification ns=2;s=var1_val {val1}")
            logs.append(f"datachange_notification ns=2;s=var2_val {val2}")
            print(val1)
            print(val2)
        print("log created")
        return logs,dt


    def store_values(self,logs,dt):
        with open(f"logs/message_{dt}.log", 'w+') as logfile:
            logfile.write('\n'.join(logs))
            time.sleep(10)


c = client()
var1,var2 = c.connect_to_server()
while True:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=c.read_from_client, args=(var1,var2))
    logs,dt = t1.run()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=c.store_values, args=(logs,dt))
    t2.run()
```

This is my approach so far, yet I have only a very small experience with multithreading. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems here. There may be others. I didn't look too deeply into what you are trying to do.

---

You call `t1.run()` and `t2.run()`. That's usually a mistake. Your main program does not create any threads. It creates two `Thread` *objects,* but that's not the same thing. No actual threads will be created if you don't call `t1.start()` and `t2.start()`.

When you call the `start()` function, it creates a new thread, and then the *new thread* calls the `run()` function.

---

Your `t1.run()` function returns a value. But when you `start` a separate thread, the value returned by the `run()` function will be ignored. If you need to communicate a value from one thread to another, you will have to do it by changing the value of a variable or the state of an object that both threads can access.

---

There is no loop in your `store_values` function, and you only ever try to invoke the function one time. Therefore, it will only ever call `logfile.write('\n'.join(logs))` *one time.*

---

> I've set two threads: one thread for reading the client, and the second one for storing the data.

I would do it with just one thread, and instead of blindly sleeping for ten seconds each time around the loop, I would *compute* the amount of time to sleep so that it would read from the client precisely* once every ten seconds. Something like this (pseudo code):

```py
import time

next_wakeup_time = time.time()
while True:
    next_wakeup_time = next_wakeup_time + 10.0
    ...read from the client...
    ...store the values...
    time_now = time.time()
    sleep_duration = next_wakeup_time - time_now
    if sleep_duration >= 0.0:
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)
    else:
        print("Uh Oh! Missed a deadline!")
        ...maybe recover from error if we missed a "hard" real-time
        ...deadline (see below.)
        next_wakeup_time = time.time()
```

* The precision will be limited by the precision of the system clock on whatever operating system and hardware platform you are using. Your need to do something once every ten seconds is an example of a [*real-time requirement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing). If it's *essential* for your program to read the server "at the right time," then that's called a *hard* real-time requirement. On the other hand, if it's "just a good idea," then that's a *soft* real-time requirement.

If "the right time" is a window of around a millisecond or less, then you're probably going to want to run on dedicated hardware running a specialized [*real-time operating system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) (a.k.a., "RTOS"). If the window is tens of milliseconds or more, then you probably can get by with a normal desktop or server OS, but you still might want to run on dedicated hardware (i.e., on a computer that isn't running other programs at the same time.)